# How would I be able to close this class and open a new class with a JButton and an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am trying to make a game menu where if you click a button it goes onto another window (which I made in another class). With my current code, the window does not close, rather it goes invisible.

I have tried using `System.exit(0);` and `dispose();`. However, `System.exit(0)` does not open the other window and `dispose();` does not completely exit the window.

In the `actionPerformed` method right now I use

`Class.main(new String[0]);` to open the new class and I use `setVisible(false);` to close the current class. But this does not accomplish what I want.

The output I expect is when you click one of the JButton's it completely closes the PongGUI class and opens the corresponding class.

Comment: `System.exit(0)` will terminate the JVM. *"dispose() does not completely exit the window"* - You'll need to expand on this as it doesn't make sense

Comment: *"The output I expect is when you click one of the JButton's it completely closes the PongGUI class and opens the corresponding class."* - I don't think you full understand what's going on here, but I'm curious by what you mean *"completely closes the PongGUI class"*